# Multiple image upload with angular js and spring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

I want to upload multiple image .For that i am using angular js and spring mvc.Here I am able to get all the files in angular js but when i am clicking on upload  ,its not showing error and its not going inside the spring controller too. I jjust want to print text with there in system.out.print statement.Please help me out.

Thank you.

Here is my html:-

```
 <div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="multiple">Select File</div>

    Drop File:
    <div ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="files" class="drop-box"
        ngf-drag-over-class="dragover" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="true"
        accept="image/*,application/pdf">Drop pdfs or images here or click to upload</div>
    <div ngf-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>
    Files:

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="f in filesDetails" style="font:smaller">{{f.name}}</li>
    </ul>

</div>
</div>

<div>
         <button class="" ng-click="uploadImage()">Upload Image</button>
</div>
```

Here is my controller.js:-

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$http', function($scope, Upload, $http) {
    $scope.filesDetails = [];
    $scope.$watch('files', function() {

        $scope.upload($scope.files);
    });


    $scope.upload = function(files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                if (files[i].type == 'image/jpeg' || files[i].type == 'image/png') {
                    $scope.filesDetails.push(files[i]);
                } else {
                    alert("This kind of file is not Valid");

                }
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.uploadImage = function() {



        alert("uploading");
        var formData = {
            file: $scope.filesDetails
        };
        console.log(formData.file);

        var imagePost = $http.post(
            'http://localhost:8080/orion-orbit/newclue/doUpload',
            formData,
            {
                transformRequest: 
                    function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
                    return data;
                },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            });


        imagePost.success(function(data, status,
            headers, config) {
            alert("sucess" + status);

        });
        imagePost.error(function(data, status,
            headers, config) {
            alert("Error" + status);
            alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({
                data: data
            }));

        });
    }
}]);
```

Here is my spring Controller:-
@Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/newclue")
public class ClueController {

@RequestMapping(value="/doUpload" , method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = "multipart/form-data")

    public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
    {
    System.out.println("inside controller of image Upload");

    }
```

}

This is my web.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error-pages/404-error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error-pages/500-error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Here is my spring-config-file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.orion.orbit.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/o2_db" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.orion.orbit.model.CountryCode</value>
                <value>com.orion.orbit.model.CityCode</value>
                <value>com.orion.orbit.model.ClueData</value>               
                <value>com.orion.orbit.model.ClueAns</value>
                <value>com.orion.orbit.model.AnsClueMap</value>
                <value>com.orion.orbit.model.ClueTag</value>
                <value>com.orion.orbit.model.ClueTagMap</value>
                <value>com.orion.orbit.model.NewClueRequestVO</value>
                <value>com.orion.orbit.model.UploadFile</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="simpleMappingExceptionResolver" class="com.orion.orbit.resolver.MySimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <map>
                <entry key="Exception" value="error"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="clueDao" class="com.orion.orbit.dao.ClueDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="clueServices" class="com.orion.orbit.services.ClueServicesImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various points to check

1. From your URL , your root context seems like orion-orbit, 
   'http://localhost:8080/orion-orbit/newclue/doUpload',
   So you have to map your requestMapping to    @RequestMapping(value="/newclue/doUpload"
2. It also depends on how you are mapping URLs, check your web.xml if you have configured correctly the request dispatcher and if you have any URL redirections.
3. And you should have Spring multipart resolver bean defined in your applicationContext.xml  to resolve multipart uploads.

Example:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```